# Query for multiple values of the same property with queryDSL and Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, querydsl

Is there a way to query for multiple values of the same property with Spring DataREST JPA and querydsl? I am not sure what the format of the query URL should be and if I need extra customization in my bindings. I couldn't find anything in documentation. If I have a "student" table in my database with a "major" column with corresponding Student entity I would assume that querying for all students which have "math" and "science" majors would look like http://localhost:8080/students?major=math&major=science. However in this query only the first part is being taken and major=science is ignored

Answer (score 0):

Below example customizes Querydsl web support to perform collection in operation. URI `/students?major=sword&major=magic` searches for students with `major` in `["sword", "magic"]`.

Entity and repository

```java
public class Student {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String major;
}

public interface StudentRepos extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Student, Long>,
                                      QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Student>,
                                      QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QStudent> {

    @Override
    default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QStudent root) {

        bindings.bind(root.major)
                .all((path, value) -> Optional.of(path.in(value)));
    }
}
```

Test data

```java
new Student("Arthur", "sword");
new Student("Merlin", "magic");
new Student("Lancelot", "lance");
```

Controller

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/students")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StudentController {

    private final StudentRepos studentRepos;

    @GetMapping
    ResponseEntity<List<Student>> getAll(Predicate predicate) {

        Iterable<Student> students = studentRepos.findAll(predicate);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(StreamSupport.stream(students.spliterator(), false)
                                              .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

Test case

```java
    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    public void queryAll() {

        mockMvc.perform(get("/students"))
               .andExpect(status().isOk())
               .andExpect(jsonPath("$").isArray())
               .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(3)))
               .andDo(print());
    }

    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    void querySingleValue() {

        mockMvc.perform(get("/students?major=sword"))
               .andExpect(status().isOk())
               .andExpect(jsonPath("$").isArray())
               .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)))
               .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].name").value("Arthur"))
               .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].major").value("sword"))
               .andDo(print());
    }


    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    void queryMultiValue() {

        mockMvc.perform(get("/students?major=sword&major=magic"))
               .andExpect(status().isOk())
               .andExpect(jsonPath("$").isArray())
               .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
               .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].name").value("Arthur"))
               .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].major").value("sword"))
               .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].name").value("Merlin"))
               .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].major").value("magic"))
               .andDo(print());
    }
```

The full Spring Boot application is in [Github](https://github.com/yejianfengblue/spring-data-jpa-querydsl-web-support)

Comment: How multivalue binding will work on the join table with many to many relationships? Let's say I have courses table and connect a course to a student via join table. How do I search for students which take multiple courses?

Comment: I'm not good at querydsl. It would help if you show me how to construct a `Collection.containsAll(Collection)` querydsl call. Because there is only `CollectionExpressionBase.contains(E child)` but no `CollectionExpressionBase.containsAll(...)`. Then apply that to StudentRepos.customize().